# Remover um objecto dentro de um array mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Eu tenho o seguinte documento dentro de uma collection em mongodb:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5988efbb742568478c6a086f"),
    "cliente" : "exemplo@dominio.com",
    "lista_compras" : [ 
        {
            "id_produto" : ObjectId("5983bb21834000b1b8e7978f"),
            "produto" : "Leite Nido em Lata 87 copos",
            "preco" : 5250,
            "imagem" : "../../images/produtos/candando/nido.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "id_produto" : ObjectId("5983bb21834000b1b8e7978f"),
            "produto" : "Leite Nido em Lata 87 copos",
            "preco" : 5250,
            "imagem" : "../../images/produtos/candando/nido.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "id_produto" : ObjectId("5983bb21834000b1b8e7978f"),
            "produto" : "Leite Nido em Lata 87 copos",
            "preco" : 5250,
            "imagem" : "../../images/produtos/candando/nido.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "id_produto" : ObjectId("5983bb21834000b1b8e7978a"),
            "produto" : "Banana prata cultivada no sul de Angola 100gr",
            "preco" : 689,
            "imagem" : "../../images/produtos/candando/banana.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "id_produto" : ObjectId("5983bb21834000b1b8e7978b"),
            "produto" : "Atum amiga de óleo vegetal",
            "preco" : 120450,
            "imagem" : "../../images/produtos/candando/atum.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "id_produto" : ObjectId("5983bb21834000b1b8e7978a"),
            "produto" : "Banana prata cultivada no sul de Angola 100gr",
            "preco" : 689,
            "imagem" : "../../images/produtos/candando/banana.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "id_produto" : ObjectId("5983bb21834000b1b8e7978a"),
            "produto" : "Banana prata cultivada no sul de Angola 100gr",
            "preco" : 689,
            "imagem" : "../../images/produtos/candando/banana.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "id_produto" : ObjectId("5983bb21834000b1b8e7978a"),
            "produto" : "Banana prata cultivada no sul de Angola 100gr",
            "preco" : 689,
            "imagem" : "../../images/produtos/candando/banana.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Pretendo remover um objecto de cada vez. Eu uso o seguinte comando:

```
db.carrinhos.update(
    {cliente: "exemplo@dominio.com"},
    {$pull: {lista_compras: { id_produto: ObjectId("5983bb21834000b1b8e7978f") }}}
)
```

Acontece que apaga todos os objectos com o `id` especificado. Existe uma forma de eu apagar um de cada vez?

Comment: Resolvi adicionando um valor chave a cada documento dentro do array e fui eliminando com base da mesma.

Comment: Sugestão: adiciona o teu comentário como resposta e marca como aceita! assim tua pergunta fica como respondida e ajuda quem está procurando por uma resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi adicionando um valor chave a cada documento dentro do array e fui eliminando com base da mesma. Antes eu tinha a minha estrutura assim:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5988efbb742568478c6a086f"),
    "cliente" : "exemplo@dominio.com",
    "lista_compras" : [ 
        {
            "id_produto" : ObjectId("5983bb21834000b1b8e7978f"),
            "produto" : "Leite Nido em Lata 87 copos",
            "preco" : 5250,
            "imagem" : "../../images/produtos/candando/nido.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "id_produto" : ObjectId("5983bb21834000b1b8e7978f"),
            "produto" : "Leite Nido em Lata 87 copos",
            "preco" : 5250,
            "imagem" : "../../images/produtos/candando/nido.jpg"
        }
}
```

E agora eu tenho assim: (adicionei o campo chave `id_produto_carrinho`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5988efbb742568478c6a086f"),
    "cliente" : "exemplo@dominio.com",
    "lista_compras" : [ 
        {
            "id_produto_carrinho" : ObjectId("598f02b2cc8bc4427823f0ee"),
            "id_produto" : ObjectId("5983bb21834000b1b8e7978f"),
            "produto" : "Leite Nido em Lata 87 copos",
            "preco" : 5250,
            "imagem" : "../../images/produtos/candando/nido.jpg"
        }, 
        {
            "id_produto_carrinho" : ObjectId("598f02b2cc8bc4427823f0ef"),
            "id_produto" : ObjectId("5983bb21834000b1b8e7978f"),
            "produto" : "Leite Nido em Lata 87 copos",
            "preco" : 5250,
            "imagem" : "../../images/produtos/candando/nido.jpg"
        }
}
```

Quando eu quero eliminar ou editar, faço-o com base no campo chave que eu adicionei a cada array.

Comment: Célio e como fez isso? Poderia adicionar o código? Vai ficar mais clara sua resposta.

Comment: @Marconi, feito.

Answer (score 0):

Essa é uma questão que quebrou minha cabeça tambem, mais a solução como sempre é simples, rs, busque em todo o documento o nome do seu array e delete o Id correspondente do documento

```
     db.getCollection('compras').update({}, {
        $pull: { "lista_compras": { 
        "_id": ObjectId("5983bb21834000b1b8e7978a"))
         }}})
```